How to set json data in metadata to gcp project
I am using below command to set metadata.
Command:
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata csp="{\"default-src\":[\"'*'\",\"'self'\"]}"
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.project-info.add-metadata) argument --metadata: Bad syntax for dict arg: [\self]}].

The issue you're encountering is likely due to improper escaping of the JSON string in the command. When using gcloud, you need to make sure that the JSON string is correctly escaped to prevent any parsing errors.
Here's how you can set JSON data in metadata for a GCP project using gcloud:
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata csp='{ "default-src": ["'*'", "'self'"] }'

In this command, the JSON string is correctly escaped. Notice the usage of single quotes (') around the entire JSON string to avoid conflicts with the double quotes (") inside the JSON.

Its not working.
